# Connecting the unconnected

Tags: word, connections-puzzle

What connects/links all the following:

1. Green
2. Wednesday
3. 2nd July of a normal year
4. Fa
5. Part of a type of software attack

?

Also explain how each are connected with the found word / concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for might be

> MIDDLE (or perhaps some equivalent like CENTRE, but MIDDLE is better).

Green

> is the middle of the usual seven-way decomposition of light: R O Y **G** B I V.

Wednesday

> is the middle of the week if you count from Sunday: Su Mo Tu **We** Th Fr Sa. (The German for Wednesday is Mittwoch, "mid-week".)

2nd July of a normal year

> is the 183rd of its 365 days.

Fa

> is the middle of the seven degrees of the major scale in tonic sol-fa notation. (Note: originally the question said "La" and I speculated it might have been meant to be "Fa".)

Part of a type of software attack

> Man-in-the-**middle**.

Comment: Could "La" occur somewhere near the middle of a dictionary?

Comment: "La" for Lanthanum, atomic number 57 – not in the middle of the table, but close to the middle of the atomic numbers? (currently we're around ~118?)

Comment: That's somewhat plausible.

Comment: la is the middle line in tenor clef, but that seems a little contrived

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, good one. Edited my question, as it was my mistake to provide 'La' in the place of 'Fa'.

Answer (score 7):

The common theme is ...

> ... things in the **middle**.

Green

> Green is the 4th of the seven colours of the visible light spectrum: ROY **G** BIV.

Wednesday

> Wednesday is the middle of the working week (Mon–Fri) and the middle of the week when Sunday is seen as the first day. (Fun fact: The German name of Wednesday is *Mittwoch* – middle of the week.

2nd July of a normal year

> This is the 183rd day of a non-leap year, which sits in the middle of the 365 days.

La

> La is one of the notes of the Solmisation: do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti. I'm not quite sure why this is the middle -- it isn't in the middle of the seven or eight notes of a scale and it doesn't sit in the middle of the staves.

Part of a type of software attack

> This refers to the [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: @M Oehm...good one. You got it correct. Yes, it was my mistake that I did not mention the mddile note/staff correctly. Corrected it in the question. Thanks.